# Sonar indicator still red

Tags: sonarqube, indicator, sonarqube-4.0

I’m contacting you regarding  one Problem i encountered with indicator of Sonar, and I need your help, the problem is : In the previous analysis of one project there were 313 issues, so they made some improvements and triggered a new build , then the issues reduced to 302 but still the arrow mark beside the issue (indicator) is RED and UPWARDS.

In below the screenshot of the analysis :

-Before :
[image]

And as you can see the value are lower than the first and the indicator still red and upward, can you help us to understand why we have this indicator and if  this is an sonar Bug ?

System info :

Sonar Version : 4.0

Thank you in advance for your response

Regards,
Youssef

Answer (score 0):

The computation of the trend is not only based on the last two analysis but on all the analysis done in the past 30 days. So if you had for instance a first analysis with 0 issues, that's expected to get this icon.